# How do you vertically center multi-line text in another element in the Sketch app?

Tags: sketch-app, alignment

I wasn't able to snap a textbox with multiple lines to the center of a slice because it would only snap to the top line of text.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The workaround is to resize to the full height of the slice.

[image: Resize to full height of slice]

Then use the vertical align button to make sure the text is always in the middle no matter how many lines are in the text.

[image: Text formatting box]